# To get data from sensors and upload them to a database

Tags: ios, database, arduino

I have a question about arduino world. I've been wondering about how I can get data from a sensor - maybe it's connected arduino machine - and upload that data to a database on the internet environment. Is this possible ? Would you please share your experience and thoughts ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to get the sensor data on the Arduino, have the Arduino speak to a host PC over serial, and let the host PC post the data to an internet site.

Another way is to mount an "ethernet shield [like this](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-ethernet-shield-2) to your Arduino, and compose a tiny http message directly from your Arduino.

Beyond those broad outlines, we'll have to have specific programming questions to help you more, because this is more of a project than a question appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Good luck, and ask for specific help when you need it.

Comment: Thank you so much, your response makes my mind clear for further questions.

Comment: @erkutbas Quite welcome.  You could upvote and Accept my answer as way of thanks ;)